# How to get Text coordinates using PyUNO with OpenOffice writer

Tags: python, openoffice-writer, pyuno

I have a python script that successfully does a search and replace in an OpenOffice Writer document using PyUNO. I wanna to ask how to get the coordinate of found text?

```
import string
search = document.createSearchDescriptor()
search.SearchString = unicode('find')
#search.SearchCaseSensitive = True
#search.SearchWords = True
found = document.findFirst(search)
if found:
    #log.debug('Found %s' % find)
    ## any code here help to get the coordinate of found text?
    pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinates"?
Position of text in a document depends on page/char sizes and other facts (screen/print resoltuion). 
What would you like to do with such values?

Comment: purpose question is that I want to add a 'specified' text in odt file, and detect this text's postion for page size adjusting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some StarBASIC code to find the page number of a search expression in a Writer document:

```
SUB find_page_number()

oDoc = ThisComponent
oViewCursor = oDoc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
oSearchFor = "My Search example"

oSearch = oDoc.createSearchDescriptor()
With oSearch
   .SearchRegularExpression = False
   .SearchBackwards = False
   .setSearchString(oSearchFor)
End With

oFirstFind = oDoc.findFirst(oSearch)


If NOT isNull(oFirstFind) Then
    oViewCursor.gotoRange(oFirstFind, False)
    MsgBox oViewCursor.getPage()
Else
   msgbox "not found: " & oSearchFor
End If
```

Hope this helps you